# No i32/f64 fallback when using pow()

Tags: rust

With the following:

```
4.pow(2)
```

I get:

```
error: no method named `pow` found for type `_` in the current scope
```

I have to be more explicit about it, e.g.:

```
4_i32.pow(2)
```

With floats, I get a similar problem (and solution), where:

```
4.0.powf(2.0)
```

Must also be explicit:

```
4.0_f64.powf(2.0)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe this is because the fallback only happens when all the constraints on the literal have been considered (and it finds that there *aren't* any).

In this case, to know what the type of `4` is, it has to know what `pow` is.  But `pow` is defined separately for each integral type.  So to know what `pow` you're talking about, it has to know what the type of `4` is.  But to know what the type of `4` is... and so on.

Comment: And what if the `4` is a variable instead? I can't get `pow` to work on variables at all: _no method named `pow` found for type `f64` in the current scope_.

Comment: @bluenote10 For floats, you should use [powf](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.powf) for floating point exponents, and [powi](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.powi) for integer exponents.